# How to fetch a distinct list of related models for a collection of models in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Consider the following example.
Let's say we have a collection of Exams.
Each Exam can have multiple Students that took it.

So, on our `Exam` model, we created a relationship `students` which allows me to get all the students for any given exam.

Now the following question arrives:

> How can we get a list of students that took any of the exams

So basically, I need a distinct list of all exams.

I get to the point that I can fetch all the exams, and eager load all the students:

```
$exams = Exams::with('students')->where('somecondition', 'somevalue')->get();
```

Now I'm a bit confused what would be the optimal way of getting a distinct list of students.  I'm not even sure what the best way is to getting the students from all of these exams?  Is the `->each` method on that collection the way to go?

I have tried quite a few things, but they are either over complicated, and therefore unreadable, or they don't do what I want / need.

Comment: Where flag that student passed exam is stored? 
Have you pivot table (like `exams_students`)?

Comment: Hi - yes, they are in a pivot table.  exam and student is just an example, but you are correct that there is a pivot table, and polymorph at the side of an exam, so I need to start my query from the exam...

Comment: also - you don't need to validate anything on the pivot now - I just want the list of all students that are linked to the exam.  It's that simple.  I just don't see what the best option is using Laravel / Eloquent.  In the above example, $exams has the collection, and eagerloaded all studens; what's the best way to get a collection of unique students...

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent has powerfull `whereHas` method.
Given that you have have many-to-many relationship your code will look like:

```
$students = Student::whereHas('exams', function($q) {
   $q->wherePivot('passed', 1);
})->get();
```

You can set as many conditions as you want in closure.

Also `has` method will return "list of all students that are linked to the exam" (any exam):

```
$students = Student::has('exams')->get();
```

See section "Querying Relationship Existence" in ["Querying Relations"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) sections for more details.